# Spring WebFlux filter to intercept request after request object deserialization

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I have a reactive WebFlux Spring Boot application (version 2.2.3.RELEASE).  I have defined a POJO called `SearchRequest` that is used in both GET and POST requests in an annotated controller:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/search")
Mono<ItemCollection> getItems(SearchRequest searchRequest);

@PostMapping(value = "/search", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
Mono<ItemCollection> getItemsPost(@RequestBody SearchRequest searchRequest);
```

There is some basic validation that needs to be accomplished, as well as a couple of possible transformations.  Some of the fields in `SearchRequest` are objects themselves, for example:

```
public class SearchRequest {

    private Fields fields;
    ...
}
```

where the `Fields` class looks like this:

```
public class Fields {

    private Set<String> include;
    private Set<String> exclude;
    ...
}
```

For HTTP POST requests, the user can simply submit a JSON object that follows this structure.  For HTTP GET requests, the API specification I'm working against allows you to simply provide a `fields` URL parameter that contains an array of field names prefixed with either "+" or "-".  I created a class that extends `PropertyEditorSupport` to parse the URL parameter and populate the `Fields` object's include and exclude sets.  This is configured in my controller using `@InitBinder`:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Fields.class, "fields", fieldsPropertyEditor);
}
```

My `SearchRequest` object supports geospatial queries using either a `bbox` value or an `intersects` value, however I need to return a 400 if both are specified.  I have tried the following methods to implement this validation, but can't find the solution I'm looking for:

1. Registering another custom editor with `WebDataBinder` for the
   `SearchRequest` class that does not specify a field.
2. Registering a validator with `WebDataBinder` (both using `setValidator` and `addValidators` methods).
3. Implementing a `WebFilter`.

Solution 1 seems to have no effect.  The editor is never called. In solution 2, the `supports` method is called with each request, but the `validate` method is never called.  Solution 3 could work, but requires me to write two sets of logic -- one for GET and one for POST, as the GET URL parameters are stored separately from the POST request body.  In addition, in order to actually inspect the request body, `exchange.getRequest.getBody()` returns a `DataBuffer` that can be used to deserialize the body into an object, but I can't directly deserialize into `SearchRequest` without my previously mentioned property editors (for GET requests).

I am really hoping to find some sort of filter/transformer/converter that I can invoke *after* the request is deserialized into a `SearchRequest` object, but before the controller handler method is called, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Can someone please advise if this is possible or if my only option is to handle GET/POST requests separately in a `WebFilter`?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer I'm looking for, but it seems to at least work for now.  Basically I just made a custom validator and annotated my `SearchRequest` parameters in my controller methods with `@Valid`.

Annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = SingleGeometryValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface SingleGeometry {
    String message () default "Request should not contain both `intersects` and `bbox`. Please choose one geometry to "
            + "search by.";
    Class<?>[] groups () default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload () default {};
}
```

Validator:

```
public class SingleGeometryValidator implements ConstraintValidator<SingleGeometry, SearchRequest> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(SearchRequest searchRequest, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return !(searchRequest.getBbox() != null && searchRequest.getIntersects() != null);
    }
}
```

Request object:

```
@Data
@SingleGeometry
public class SearchRequest {
...
}
```

Controller interface:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/search")
Mono<ItemCollection> getItems(@Valid SearchRequest searchRequest);

@PostMapping(value = "/search", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
Mono<ItemCollection> getItemsPost(@Valid @RequestBody SearchRequest searchRequest);
```